# Working with sessions and cookies in PHP

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-cookies

During sign-in I'm using following function to set cookies and session

```
protected function validateUser($userid, $ckey=0, $rememmber=0) {
    session_start();
    session_regenerate_id(true); //this is a security measure
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $userid;
    $_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    if (isset($remember) && $rememmber == 'on') {
        setcookie("user_id", $_SESSION['user_id'], time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * COOKIE_TIME_OUT, "/");
        setcookie("user_key", sha1($ckey), time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * COOKIE_TIME_OUT, "/");
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then on secure user pages, checking for `user_id` using user_id to fetch all important data about user from db

```
public function protect() {
        session_start();

        /* Secure against Session Hijacking by checking user agent */
        if (isset($_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
            if ($_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] != md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
                $this->signout();
                exit;
            }
        }

// before we allow sessions, we need to check authentication key - ckey and ctime stored in database

        /* If session not set, check for cookies set by Remember me */
        if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
            if (isset($_COOKIE['user_id']) && isset($_COOKIE['user_key'])) {
                /* we double check cookie expiry time against stored in database */

                $cookie_user_id = $_COOKIE['user_id'];
                               $stmt = $this->db->prepare("select `ckey`,`ctime` from `users` where `id` =?") or die($this->db->error);
            $stmt->bind_param("i", $cookie_user_id) or die(htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
            $stmt->execute() or die(htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
            $stmt->bind_result($ckey, $ctime) or die($stmt->error);
            $stmt->close() or die(htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
                // coookie expiry
                if ((time() - $ctime) > 60 * 60 * 24 * COOKIE_TIME_OUT) {
                    $this->signout();
                }
                /* Security check with untrusted cookies - dont trust value stored in cookie.       
                  /* We also do authentication check of the `ckey` stored in cookie matches that stored in database during login */

                if (!empty($ckey) && is_numeric($_COOKIE['user_id']) && $_COOKIE['key'] == sha1($ckey)) {
                    session_regenerate_id(); //against session fixation attacks.

                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $_COOKIE['user_id'];
                    $_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
                } else {
                    $this->signout();
                }
            } else {
                if ($page != 'main') {
                    header('Location:' . wsurl);
                    exit();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I wonder, is that enough to store only user_id and user_agent in cokkies and session for security purposes? If not, what else?

Comment: You might want to add tokens to your sessions to prevent from CSRF: http://shiflett.org/articles/cross-site-request-forgeries

Comment: You should **never** store sensitive data such as a user ID in a cookie, **always use a session**.

Comment: @animuson So, how to rememmber user then?

Comment: it's just the users id. it not like a password or anything

Comment: @AuthmanApatira Yes I agree with you. It's only some digit. animuson please explain your idea.

Comment: @RomanNewaza You want to say, to create and stoe token for every user and then fetch it from db?

Comment: I agree with @animuson as even it's just a number, we expose some internal data. Just use sessions.

Comment: @RomanNewaza how to rememmber user then?

Comment: You have to remember cookies can be edited by the user. That means every single page has to run a query to fetch the password to make sure they didn't change it. Not to mention, it allows users to bypass your login system's limited number of password tries by merely calling the logout method. You should store the user ID in the session and let the cookie just be the session ID instead, then you don't have to waste resources checking things all the time.

Comment: @animuson I partially understand you. can you please edit the code to make all things clear?

Comment: @Tural Teyyuboglu, you store your user id in session  variable.

Comment: @RomanNewaza ok. So I will fully remove cookies from the code, and leave only session. right?

Comment: yes, sessions is what you need.

Comment: @RomanNewaza but I really don't get, how can I give "rememmber me" functionality to my website without cookies. I need bit more explanation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$rs_ctime = $this->db->query("select `ckey`,`ctime` from `users` where `id` = -> '$cookie_user_id'<-")
```

Seems like here is SQL-injection. If you pass variable from GET, POST, COOKIE directly to sql-query it is a sign of injection.

Usually it is enough to store user_id and user_agent. But some payment services sometimes use verification by phone sending sms with some code and checking it. But it is usually for very safe services

Answer (score 3):

Sessions are stored on the server and you're already doing your part regenerating the session key immediately after login, per [Wikipedia's Session Hacking Prevention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking), so I'd say you're good just storing user agent and user id. I would not, however, regenerate the session id after every secure page view (eg, remove `session_regenerate_id()` from the `validateUser()` function). Wikipedia recommends only doing it once upon login... anything more than that is kind of just out of control. I would also move `session_start()` out of the functions though and up top in a nice high place in your code.

Good luck coding!

Comment: protect() is at the top of every user page. so session_start will be at the top))